# Deeply Nested, Arbitrarily lenth Definition Lists, Zebra-striped in Jquery

Tags: jquery-selectors, jquery, zebra-striping

I have a page where the markup includes nested definition lists of both random depth and random numbers of DDs associated with any DT. Thus:

```
DL
- DT
- DD
- DT
- DD
- DD
  --DL
     --DT
     --DD
     --DT
     --DD
     --DD
 -DT
 -DD
 -DD
```

I need:

1. zebra stripe the groups of DT/DDs with one another and
2. to start the even/odd sequence over for each nested list that is encountered.

   - Using :even and :odd won't work because of the extra DDs.
   - I've tried using an each loop, shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/XJ9j4/, which fixes A but ignores B. i.e. compare the background color of the 1st child dt/dd combination to the 1st parent, and consider the return to the parent list which should be blue not green.

Thoughts?

Comment: Could you show a demo, using explicit class-names, to style the `dt`/`dd` elements as you want them to look? (Just so that I can understand the question you're asking.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With my new understanding of what you want, I think this will do.  Let me know if I am still misunderstanding.

```
$("dl").each(function(){
   $this = $(this);

   $this.children("dt:even").addClass("even").nextUntil("dt").addClass("even");  
   $this.children("dt:odd").addClass("odd").nextUntil("dt").addClass("odd");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XJ9j4/8/

Comment: Unfortunately, no, I need the DT and its DDs grouped with one another. Your 1st 3 (DT, DD, DD) should all be green

Comment: @user1660678 Updated answer to what I think you mean.  let me know if I still misunderstand.

Comment: No, that was my original solution (never shown here). see: http://jsfiddle.net/kcpQh/.  When you break back to the parent loop, note the iteration starts green, but also left off at green before the nesting structure began. Both the number of DDs for any DT/DD combo is arbitrary as are the number of DT/DD groupings in a DL. Each level of the list needs to be independent from its parent or possible children.

Comment: I have to agree with @DavidThomas here.  An example showing the desired result with static classes would really help in understanding your question.  Does the situation you are describing not exist in the provided html?

Comment: @user1660678 Updated one more time, though it's possible I still misunderstand.